# hover animation not working fully after first event

Tags: jquery, animation, plugins, hover, mouseenter

warning: jquery/javascript newbie in the house.  I used the [tutorial here](http://www.webdevdoor.com/javascript-ajax/jquery-pendulum-animation-pivot-point/) to make an animation where an image swings back and forth on hover.

However, after the first hover event, the image will only go back and forth 1 time, whereas on the first hover event it swings back and forth 5 times (the number defined by swings variable).  I want it to swing the same number of times on every hover event.

I have tried changing the rotation, swings, and swingcount variables and also trying to make the pendulumrest function match the swing function, and changing the if/else statement for pendulum swing.  Nothing works - what am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var rotation = 5; 
        var initrotation = rotation;
        var swingtime = 603;
        var swings = 5;
        var swingcount = 0; 
        var startatcentre = true;

        if (startatcentre == true) {
            initrotation = 0;
        }
        $('#pendulum-child').mouseenter(function() {
            function init() {
                $('#pendulum-parent').animate({rotate: initrotation}, 0, function () {
                    $('#pendulum-parent').css("display", "block");
                    rotation *= -1;
                    swingcount++;
                    pendulumswing();                    
                });
            }

            function pendulumswing() {
                $('#pendulum-parent').animate({rotate: rotation},swingtime, "swing", function(){
                     rotation *= -1;                     
                     if (swingcount >= swings) {
                        pendulumrest(); 
                    } else {
                        swingcount++;
                        pendulumswing();                        
                    }

                });
            }   

            function pendulumrest() {
                $('#pendulum-parent').animate({rotate: 0},(swingtime/1.5), "swing");    
            }

            init(); 
        });
    });
})(jQuery);    
</script>
```

Comment: In your `init()` function, you need to re-initialize the variables to what they are set to on `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @AlexMorrise thank you. any guidance on how to do that? i tried copying them into the function but that made the animation jumpy so that must not be the correct way.

Comment: All I can think of is just copying the initializations into the `init()` function, just before the `.animate()` call, as you said. But make sure you aren't copying the `var` part (you don't want to re-declare the variables).

Comment: Also, you could take your function declarations outside of the `mouseenter` binding. Every time your mouse goes over the pendulum, you're re-declaring those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you walk through the code, then you will notice that the pendulum swing will stop only if `swingcount >= swings`. This means that the first time you move your mouse over the element, the swingcount will keep incrementing till it hits 5 and then the swinging stops.

The second time you move your mouse over the element, it will run the animation as per `init` (which I presume is resetting the position of the pendulum). It then calls `pendulumswing` which does an animation immediately. So you see the first swing. Once the first animation is over, it checks the swing count, which is still at its previous value of 6. This doesn't meet the condition and the `pendulumrest` is called instead.

So, as @Alex mentioned in his comment, you need to reset the value of swingcount to 0 before you start your animations. Implementing the thoughts in his comments, your code could be as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var rotation = 5; 
        var initrotation = rotation;
        var swingtime = 603;
        var swings = 5;
        var swingcount = 0; 
        var startatcentre = true;

        if (startatcentre == true) {
            initrotation = 0;
        }

        function init() {
            swingcount = 0;
            rotation = 5;
            $('#pendulum-parent').animate({rotate: initrotation}, 0, function () {
                $('#pendulum-parent').css("display", "block");
                rotation *= -1;
                swingcount++;
                pendulumswing();                    
            });
        }

        function pendulumswing() {
            $('#pendulum-parent').animate({rotate: rotation},swingtime, "swing", function(){
                 rotation *= -1;                     
                 if (swingcount >= swings) {
                    pendulumrest(); 
                } else {
                    swingcount++;
                    pendulumswing();                        
                }

            });
        }   

        function pendulumrest() {
            $('#pendulum-parent').animate({rotate: 0},(swingtime/1.5), "swing");    
        }

        $('#pendulum-child').mouseenter(function() {
            init(); 
        });
    });
})(jQuery);    
</script>
```

Btw, [Javascript Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752) is a very good book for learning JS. While it's not exactly a beginners book, he does explain everything properly. And I personally find it a lot more readable than the Good Parts book.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, and I really learned something thanks to your explanation.  Cheers!